# appending text to all files that starts with a string

Tags: linux, unix, shell, ksh

How do I append a string to all the files in a directory that starts with a particular string?

I tried,

```
cat mysig >> F*
```

But instead of appending contents of mysig to all files starting with F, it creates a file named "F*". Obviously wildcard doesn't seem to work.
Any alternatives?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Also how do I delete this newly created file "F*" safely?. Using

```
rm F*
```

would delete all the files starting with F which I wouldn't want.

Comment: `rm 'F*'` should do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell can't do that directly, since there will only be a single stream coming from the source program (the cat, in this case).

You need a helper program, such as [tee](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee). Try this:

```
$ cat mysig | tee -a F*
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for f in F*
do
  echo "string" >> $f
done
```

`*` is a special character - you need to quote it

```
rm 'F*'
```